# How to make a bezel in CSS or vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, figma

injection:
[image: injection]

If there is some property in the CSS to create such an angle as in the layout

The program itself does not specify this property in the tab
I tried to search there
!:
[image: !]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use clip-path css property, and here is an example:

```css
.square{
  clip-path: polygon(80% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 0% 80%, 0 0);
  
  background-color:dodgerblue;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

clip-path: polygon(80% 0%, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 0% 80%, 0 0);

for more info about this property [MDN clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)